# How can i use batch in correlation with the iterations of a query using twig?

Tags: twig, craftcms

I am trying to batch the content of a section while always batching half the amount that is to display.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('bilder').datum(['and', '>= 2019-01-01', '< 2019-12-31']).limit(-1)|batch({{loop.length/2}})%}
       <div class="column" id="verstecken">
           {% for value in entry %}
               {% set bild = value.bild.one() %}
               <img src="{{ bild.url }}" alt="{{ value.title }}">
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
{% endfor %}
```

this wont work, because *A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".*

I'm kinda stuck on this one. Not sure if batch is even the rigt thing to use.

Comment: `batch({{loop.length/2}})` is invalid syntax, just go with `batch(loop.length/2)`

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks but...
, it gives me an index error: _Undefined index: loop_
...it smh still thinks of it as index

Comment: Ah yeah is not defined outside an loop ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in two steps, first assign the result and then you can use the filter `length`, e.g.

```html
{% set records = craft.entries.section('bilder').datum(['and', '>= 2019-01-01', '< 2019-12-31']).limit(-1) %}

{% for entries in records|batch(records|length/2 %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/yje585)